# Rails 4: Set attribute value for ModelName.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an attribute on my model, `Program`, called `specialty_tour` which I would like to set to `false` for each ActiveRecord.

I attempted to do

```
Program.all.each{<set specialty_tour attribute to false ..>}
```

but `.all` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is not an ennumerable type in ruby.

thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do it as below :

```
Program.update_all specialty_tour: false
```

Read the [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method docs. This will *by pass* the validations. If you want to pass through the validation, then use [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) :

```
Program.update(Program.pluck(:id), specialty_tour: false)
```